# Minimum from a 3x3 table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I input the number `3`.

I want to find the first number in a `3x3` table for example, that is bigger than my `3`.

```
2   3   4
5   6   7
8   5   6
```

In this case, I want this formula to return `4`.

Comment: How can I know which is the first number? for column or row?

Comment: When you say "first", do you mean the *smallest* number which is bigger than 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You need this Array (CSE) formula:*

- I'm assuming that you have data in Range `A1:C3`.

  `{=MIN(IF($A$1:$C$3>3,$A$1:$C$3))}`
- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

Comment: +1 - for current versions of Excel, you don't need to finish the formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter. Enter will do.

Comment: @FlexYourData,, thanks for encouragement,, my experience says it's is wise step to work with an Array method since formula has to check cell by cell for the value in entire range,,, useful when handling huge range ☺

Comment: Glad to help you @Bogdan ,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 0):

For any size table:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,myRange*1/(myRange>3),1)
```

where `myRange` is the cell reference to your table.